# Why use GoogleAPIClient to request location updates?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-location, android-googleapiclient

I noticed that it's possible to request location updates in (at least) two different ways.

1. Using `GoogleAPIClient`:

   ```
   // Callback for when the GoogleAPIClient is connected
   @Override
   public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
       LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
           mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
   }
   ```

2. Using `LocationManager`:

   ```
   LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().
       getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);      

   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
       0, 0, locationListener);
   ```

Google seems to promote method `1` in their tutorial ["Receiving Location Updates"](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). It's unclear to me what the benefit of method `1` is, because method `2` is working just as fine for me (I'm using both methods in two different places in an app).

Comment: Check this answer, too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395614/locationmanager-uses-fusedlocationproviderapi/37396211#37396211)

Answer (score 2):

Good news, from Google Play Services version 11.0, no need to connect GoogleApiClient

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html

You don't have to handle callbacks and states(connected, connecting), just request/remove location updates, similar taste of LocationManager.

Answer (score 1):

The new method to get location updates is to use [Fused Location Provider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) in android. 
The best thing about Fused location provider API is that **you not need to worry about location updates** it gives you always latest and accurate location and updates location after a interval or on location change .
One more thing about Fused location provider API is **you don't need to think about best location provider** because it automatically choose best one suited for your hardware of  your android device.

Here is a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc) in I/O 2013, which may provide more details.